# What after push transaction?

Tags: nodeos, cleos, keosd

I have created a custom action called hash. And I have push transaction with that action successfully.
now when I fetch a transaction with transaction_id, it responds transaction object as follows:

```
{
"id": "9b1076763ad18e5818ec05b0c79609ce740a0f402807edd41f1c51ef45964170",
"trx": {
  "receipt": {
  "status": "executed",
  "cpu_usage_us": 263,
  "net_usage_words": 13,
  "trx": [
    1,{
      "signatures": [
        "SIG_K1_K123etBbWPVdSbvK7Q6smYtDnwTHofX2kmwtBAHMvE9osEwZQDvU2Sk7xLdh3qfxoPKoogGx5p8DapVnkdH1NgEj31cZ56"
      ],
      "compression": "none",
      "packed_context_free_data": "",
      "packed_trx": "2115c05d571c0b090ca800000000010000000000ea3055000000000090b1ca010000000000ea305500000000a8ed3232080000000000d0b06900"
    }
  ]
},
"trx": {
  "expiration": "2019-11-04T12:10:09",
  "ref_block_num": 7255,
  "ref_block_prefix": 2819361035,
  "max_net_usage_words": 0,
  "max_cpu_usage_ms": 0,
  "delay_sec": 0,
  "context_free_actions": [],
  "actions": [{
      "account": "eosio",
      "name": "test",
      "authorization": [{
          "actor": "eosio",
          "permission": "active"
        }
      ],
      "data": "0000000000d0b069"
    }
  ],
  "transaction_extensions": [],
  "signatures": [
    "SIG_K1_K123etBbWPVdSbvK7Q6smYtDnwTHofX2kmwtBAHMvE9osEwZQDvU2Sk7xLdh3qfxoPKoogGx5p8DapVnkdH1NgEj31cZ56"
  ],
  "context_free_data": []
}
},
"block_time": "2019-11-04T12:09:09.500",
"block_num": 12967,
"last_irreversible_block": 13763,
"traces": [{
  "receipt": {
    "receiver": "eosio",
    "act_digest": "6bdf1928863a46ebfbd4102889d2a9980e55fff3f75ed7cf8f3d713fa2e42b20",
    "global_sequence": 12978,
    "recv_sequence": 12978,
    "auth_sequence": [[
        "eosio",
        12978
      ]
    ],
    "code_sequence": 1,
    "abi_sequence": 1
  },
  "act": {
    "account": "eosio",
    "name": "test",
    "authorization": [{
        "actor": "eosio",
        "permission": "active"
      }
    ],
    "data": "0000000000d0b069"
  },
  "context_free": false,
  "elapsed": 35,
  "console": "",
  "trx_id": "9b1076763ad18e5818ec05b0c79609ce740a0f402807edd41f1c51ef45964170",
  "block_num": 12967,
  "block_time": "2019-11-04T12:09:09.500",
  "producer_block_id": null,
  "account_ram_deltas": [],
  "except": null,
  "inline_traces": []
}
]
}
```

But when I try to fetch it using the block ID I have used for this transaction then I do not see the transaction in that `cleos get block ID`

```
{
"timestamp": "2019-11-04T11:21:21.500",
"producer": "eosio",
"confirmed": 0,
"previous": "00001c5603f6eaf05c7a8a508c208850b1e59e240a507c4362a791e47aad5720",
"transaction_mroot": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"action_mroot":"a4f212c982adfd62d75199722dc41ac5ab1f391b95163574d75fb9484c6f2118",
"schedule_version": 0,
"new_producers": null,
"header_extensions": [],
"producer_signature": "SIG_K1_K9NrRp2cNA9Nbzutk7W7RUWSiheyehotZ77LgWg7NeCYmmjcohFmRNC2GqwC3PnMWqn8xAchYeaaqs3GLQBHDU5d4avZGi",
"transactions": [],
"block_extensions": [],
"id": "00001c57b259794c0b090ca8667f3e62ab9ca35c1e1f79beed9e631d9f399ea8",
"block_num": 7255,
"ref_block_prefix": 2819361035
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ref_block_num` and `ref_block_prefix` means referred block (already in chain, and observed) when transaction is written rather than the block including that transaction. If there is another chain forked before "referred block", it cannot include transaction because it doesn't have referred block in it. You can make a query with transaction ID via endpoint that supports history APIs.